# How can I access to the iPhone address book in a web app?

Tags: iphone, web-applications, contacts

I'm currently developing a web app for my company. In this application, there's a form with input fields containing informations about contacts. I would like to create a button which allows to create a contact in the address book on a click.

Is there anyway to access the address book with JavaScript or other web language ?

For example, on windows and IE we can create an ActiveX object in  JavaScript to create contacts in Outlook...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If this turns out to be possible, I'm eating my [Mighty Mouse](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB111LL/A/Wireless-Mighty-Mouse?fnode=MTY1NDA1Mg&mco=MjE0Njk1MA) ..

*I apologize for the slightly unrelated answer*

P.S: to make this answer slightly more related; you could accomplish this by creating a hybrid between a native application and a web app, where the native app will pop-up the address book and then return its data to the web app.

Comment: Never mind the mighty mouse, I'll eat my Apple wired keyboard (aluminum with the keypad!)

Comment: @Pierre, I really don't think so; Safari has no support for ActiveX (thank god) and since it is a full port, it should not have a different JavaScript api then the regular Safari, so it doesn't have any knowledge about an address book what so ever.

Comment: @phsr: Would you like to sit in a hospital just because Pierre asked this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a link that generates a file in the [vCard format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard), the iPhone version of Safari might recognize it as a contact and automatically launch the address book app when they click on the link.

It appears that this would NOT work as of iPhone 2.1 (no vCard support in safari), but it might work in 3.0 - I have seen that people will be able to send vCards via MMS on the iPhone, so maybe they'll work in safari too?  I guess you'd just have to try it to find out.

Comment: thanks Eric, this could be an idea. I'm waiting for the 3.0 and I'll see if it works.

Comment: @Pierre - well, looks like MiRAGe doesn't have to eat his keyboard after all.